# Error freemarker while instancing GreenDao

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, freemarker, greendao

When i try to instance a new DaoGenerator  inside or outside the AsyncTask it crashes my application.

Instancing the DaoGenerator:

```
Schema schema = new Schema(1,"com.example.administrator.teste");

Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");

user.addIdProperty();
user.addStringProperty("name");
user.addStringProperty("user");
user.addStringProperty("pass");

try {
    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../db/src");
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it gives the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:
>   freemarker/ext/beans/ClassIntrospector
>               at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.(BeansWrapper.java:318)
>               at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.(BeansWrapper.java:245)
>               at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.(BeansWrapper.java:196)
>               at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapperSingletonHolder.(BeansWrapperSingletonHolder.java:27)
>               at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance(BeansWrapper.java:795)
>               at freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper.(ObjectWrapper.java:49)
>               at freemarker.template.Configuration.getDefaultObjectWrapper(Configuration.java:1552)
>               at freemarker.core.Configurable.(Configurable.java:151)
>               at freemarker.template.Configuration.(Configuration.java:357)
>               at freemarker.template.Configuration.(Configuration.java:233)
>               at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.(DaoGenerator.java:61)
>               at com.example.administrator.teste.LoginActivity$CreateDatase.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:62)
>               at com.example.administrator.teste.LoginActivity$CreateDatase.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:48)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

I tried to solve this by compiling in the project freemarker but it gives the same exception.

Additional Info:

- IDE : Android Studio 1.0.1
- Java : jdk 8
- Library : GreenDao v3

Grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.teste"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:1.3.1'
    compile 'freemarker:freemarker:2.3.9'
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.21'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from http://freemarker.org/freemarkerdownload.html :

```
Until about 2007 the Maven group name was "freemarker" instead of "org.freemarker", 
and as the XML comment above says, this can cause problems, 
as Maven will see them as two independent artifacts with no version conflict. 
If you run into this issue, find the dependency that depends on the old FreeMarker, 
and add this to your application's POM where you declare the problematic dependency:

<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>freemarker<!-- Do NOT use this org-less group! --></groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Try this in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
  <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.21</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>de.greenrobot</groupId>
  <artifactId>greendao-generator</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Or with Gradle:

```
compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.21'
compile('de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:1.3.1') {
    exclude module: 'freemarker'
}
```